# remove url parameters using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like this url:

```
http://bulk-click.startappsdasdasice.com/tracking/adClick?d=scsdc%20cdcsc%20c
```

to become

```
bulk-click.startappsdasdasice.com/tracking
```

I need this kind of pattern for all urls. so the string with the question mark and onward need to be deleted

Comment: Doing a POST instead of a GET could solve your issue too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways for this one of them is

```js
var url="http://bulk-click.startappsdasdasice.com/tracking/adClick?d=scsdc%20cdcsc%20c";
var suburl=url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf("/")).replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, '');
console.log(suburl);
```

Comment: Can u write one more example which is not working with my code in your question?

Comment: it works but i updated the question. i need to get rid of the http:// or https:// part as well

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a regular expression

```js
var myRe = new RegExp('([http|https]://)(.+)(\/.+\?)', 'g');
var myArray = myRe.exec('http://bulk-click.startappsdasdasice.com/tracking/adClick?d=scsdc%20cdcsc%20c');
console.log(myArray[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `URL` interface to achieve this and substring till the last pathname (/adClick)

```js
let url = new URL('http://bulk-click.startappsdasdasice.com/tracking/adClick?d=scsdc%20cdcsc%20c');

console.log(url.host + url.pathname.substring(0, url.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')))
```

[URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)
[lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)
[substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Answer (score 0):

Good idea. But use lenght const, because it assigns meaning specifically to this URL, and not to all the meanings of the URL above

const myRe = new RegExp('([http|https]://)(.+)(/.+\?)', 'g');
const myArray = myRe.exec('http://bulk-click.startappsdasdasice.com/tracking/adClick?d=scsdc%20cdcsc%20c');
console.log(myArray[2]);